# Suppose $\phi$:G$\rightarrow$G' is surjective.Let H be a normal subgroup of G containing Ker($\phi$). Let H'= $\phi$(H). Prove that G/H$\simeq$G'/H'.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose $\phi$:G$\rightarrow$G' is surjective.Let H be a normal subgroup of G containing Ker($\phi$). Let H'= $\phi$(H). Prove that G/H $\simeq$ G'/H'.
I already know that H' is a normal subgroup of G'.
By the Fundamental Homomorphism Theorem. 
G/Ker($\phi$)$\simeq$$\phi$[G]=G' (because $\phi$ is onto)
H/Ker($\phi$)$\simeq$$\phi$[H]=H'
Since H and Ker($\phi$) are normal subgroups of G and Ker($\phi$) is a subgroup of H.
By Third Isomorphism Theorem, G/H$\simeq$(G/Ker($\phi$))/(H/Ker($\phi$))
$\Rightarrow$ G/H=(G/Ker($\phi$))/(H/Ker($\phi$)) , G/Ker($\phi$)$\simeq$G' ,and H/Ker($\phi$)$\simeq$H'
$\Rightarrow$ G/H$\simeq$G'/H'
Is there a mistake in this process? If so, where does it need correction?

Comment: This looks fine but you may want to justify why $G/\operatorname{ker}\phi \cong G'$ and $H/\operatorname{ker}\phi \cong H'$ implies $(G/\operatorname{ker}\phi)/(H/\operatorname{ker}\phi) \cong G'/H'$.